# Controlling Pong Paddles using Serial Port Protocol received from a Bluetooth module

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino

In case anyone else in the future needs to figure this out I was able to solve the original problem of controlling paddles for a pong game using a bluetooth serial module using the following code:

I included the following at the top of the program

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int incomingP1Byte = 0;   // variable to store serial data
int paddle1Val = 0;     
int paddle2Val = 0;     
int flag = 0;
SoftwareSerial player1Serial(2, 3); // Initialize SoftwareSerial (RX, TX) for the bluetooth connections
```

Then accessed the paddles with the following code in void loop()

```
if(player1Serial.available() > 0)
{     
  incomingP1Byte = player1Serial.read();  
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingP1Byte);
    // delay 10 milliseconds to allow serial update time
    delay(10);

  flag=0;
}

//check incoming byte for direction


if (incomingP1Byte == 49)
  {
    player1Serial.println(paddle1Val--);
    delay(10);
      }

else if (incomingP1Byte == 50)
  {
    player1Serial.println(paddle1Val++);
    delay(10);
    }
    //-------------------------------right paddle  
    else if (incomingP1Byte == 51)
  {
    player1Serial.println(paddle2Val--);
    delay(10);
    }

     else if (incomingP1Byte == 52)
  {
    player1Serial.println(paddle2Val++);
    delay(10);
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are encountering?  Have you tried to make the program work and failed?  In what way did the program fail?

Comment: Thanks for replying dg99, I made some changes to the original question and added more code from the original program.  The changes I made caused the left paddle to disappear and sending signals over bluetooth is causing the program to slow down dramatically until I stop sending the signals.